# Why is my permission denied? MySQL server not running on XAMPP. Device is M1 Macbook Air

Tags: mysql, xampp

Last login: Thu Jun  8 15:58:07 on ttys000
illuminati_gc_0@GGCMacBookAir ~ % sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
Password:
Starting MariaDB
.2023-06-08 16:00:07 4651 mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/GGCMacBookAir.local.err'.
2023-06-08 16:00:07 4651 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/GGCMacBookAir.local.err' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server: line 264: kill: (4651) - No such process
ERROR!
illuminati_gc_0@GGCMacBookAir ~ %

I expected the problem to be solved and the MySQL server on XAMPP should be running

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.